# Fallback image if no image found in rss feed

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I have an rss feed fetching the latest items from a local news paper. I started this work day with a fatal error because they posted a news article without an enclosed image. What I want is to add a conditional tag to show a default image if there is not image enclosed.

My code is like this:

```
<?php
function read_rss($display=0,$url='') {
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($url);
$itemArr = array();
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    if ($display == 0) {
        break;
    }
    $itemRSS = array (
        'title'       => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'description' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link'        => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'pubdate'     => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'artikkelbilde' => $node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->getAttribute('url')
    );
    array_push($itemArr, $itemRSS);
    $display--;
}
return $itemArr;
}
?>
<div class="prl-span-12 prl-panel clearfix">
<h5 class="prl-block-title default"><a href="http://h-a.no">Lokale nyheter</a></h5>
<div class="prl-grid prl-grid-divider">
<?php
$items = read_rss(3, 'http://www.h-a.no/rss/rssfeed.aspx?subject1=1');
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
echo '<div class="prl-span-4"><article class="prl-article"><a class="prl-thumbnail" href="' . $item['link'] . '" title="'.$item['title'].'"><span class="prl-overlay"><img src="'. $item['artikkelbilde'] .'" alt="'.$item['title'].'"><span class="prl-overlay-area o-ha"></span></span></a><h6 class="prl-article-title"><a href="' . $item['link'] . '" title="'.$item['title'].'">'.$item['title'].'</a></h6></article>
    </div>';    
}
```

I have tried using some of the conditional codes found here, but I still get  this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on null in /home/4/h/hamarradioen/www/wp-content/themes/presslayer-hr/inc/nyhetsfeed-hamar.php on line 18

Comment: can you show what you have tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: I tried adding this in the foreach loop

 `foreach ( $items as $item ) {
$sakbilde = $item['artikkelbilde'];
if ($sakbilde === null) {
    $sakbilde = 'http://hamarradioen.no/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/hamararbeiderblad900x600.jpg';
}`

And then changed the variable in the img src to say $sakbilde instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if `$node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)` returns something to you. For example:

```
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    if ($display == 0) {
        break;
    }

    $itemRSS = array (
            'title'       => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'description' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'link'        => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'pubdate'     => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
            'artikkelbilde' => false,
        );
    $enc_node = $node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0);
    if (!empty($enc_node)) {
        $itemRSS['artikkelbilde'] = $enc_node->getAttribute('url');
    }

    array_push($itemArr, $itemRSS);
    $display--;
}
```

Later you can check if `artikkelbilde` not empty and do what you need:

```
if ($item['artikkelbilde']) {
    echo 'One thing';
} else {
    echo 'Another thing';
}
```

Comment: But I would still need these lines of code to go somewhere:

`array_push($itemArr, $itemRSS);  $display--;  }  return $itemArr;`

Comment: It worked. See my answer for the complete solution. Thank you u_mulder

Answer (score 0):

I did this now, and it seems to have worked:

```
<?php function read_rss($display=0,$url='') {
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($url);
$itemArr = array();
foreach ($doc->getElementsByTagName('item') as $node) {
    if ($display == 0) {
        break;
    }
    $itemRSS = array (
        'title'       => $node->getElementsByTagName('title')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'description' => $node->getElementsByTagName('description')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'link'        => $node->getElementsByTagName('link')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'pubdate'     => $node->getElementsByTagName('pubDate')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'artikkelbilde' => false
    );
$enc_node = $node->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0);
if (!empty($enc_node)) {
$itemRSS['artikkelbilde'] = $enc_node->getAttribute('url');
}
    array_push($itemArr, $itemRSS);
    $display--;
}
return $itemArr;
}
?>
<div class="prl-span-12 prl-panel clearfix">
<h5 class="prl-block-title default"><a href="http://h-a.no">Lokale nyheter</a></h5>
<div class="prl-grid prl-grid-divider">
<?php
$items = read_rss(3, 'http://www.h-a.no/rss/rssfeed.aspx?subject1=1');
foreach ( $items as $item ) {
$sakbilde = $item['artikkelbilde'];
if ($item['artikkelbilde']) {
$sakbilde = $item['artikkelbilde'];
}
else {
$sakbilde = 'http://hamarradioen.no/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/hamararbeiderblad900x600.jpg'; }

echo '<div class="prl-span-4"><article class="prl-article"><a class="prl-thumbnail" href="' . $item['link'] . '" title="'.$item['title'].'">
<span class="prl-overlay"><img src="'. $sakbilde .'" alt="'.$item['title'].'"><span class="prl-overlay-area o-ha"></span></span></a> <h6 class="prl-article-title"><a href="' . $item['link'] . '" title="'.$item['title'].'">'.$item['title'].'</a></h6></article>
    </div>'; }
```